# Force the end of coroutine asyncio

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm trying to understand coroutines in python, but I have some troubles grasping how I could end one.

I try to understand the following code :

```
async def send_recieve():
    async with websockets.connect(*parameters*) as _ws:
            async def send():
                while True:
                    #function send...
            async def recieve():
                while True:
                    #function recieve...
                    if #condition met:
                        break
            send_result, receive_result = await asyncio.gather(send(), receive())
asyncio.run(send_receive())
```

When the condition is met, the *recieve* function is ended, but the *send* function keep working and I can't end the whole *send_recieve* async.
I tried to sum up the code to be more clear, I can share the whole version if it's easier to understand.
I get that I miss a condition in the *send* function fulfilled when the *recieve* function is ended but I can't understand how I can write it.

If I try to add loop.stop() if the condition is met, it raises the error "RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed."

The whole code is the following :

```
async def send_receive():
    print(f'Connecting websocket to url ${URL}')
    async with websockets.connect(
        URL,
        extra_headers=(("Authorization", auth_key),),
        ping_interval=5,
        ping_timeout=20
    ) as _ws:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
        print("Receiving SessionBegins ...")
        session_begins = await _ws.recv()
        print(session_begins)
        print("Sending messages ...")

        async def send():
            while True:
                try:
                    data = stream.read(FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)
                    data = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf-8")
                    json_data = json.dumps({"audio_data":str(data)})
                    await _ws.send(json_data)
                except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError as e:
                    print(e)
                    assert e.code == 4008
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    assert False, "Not a websocket 4008 error"
                await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
          
            return True
      
        async def receive():
            while True:
                try:
                    result_str = await _ws.recv()
                    majtext = json.loads(result_str)['text']
                    print(majtext)

                except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError as e:
                    print(e)
                    assert e.code == 4008
                    return
                except Exception as e:
                    assert False, "Not a websocket 4008 error"

                if json.loads(result_str)['message_type'] == 'FinalTranscript':
                    break   
      
        send_result, receive_result = await asyncio.gather(send(), receive())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(send_receive())
```

Comment: When you say "I have the following code," do you mean that you wrote it?  Or do you mean that you're trying to understand it?  Your `send` function appears to be an infinite loop with no break or return, so it will never terminate.  The `gather` function will not return until all the tasks you send to it are done, and one of those tasks is the `send` function.  So your program is stuck there.  What would you like it to do?

Comment: Adding to @PaulCornelius comment, when a task it's running no ther task can run at the same time until it gets done or executes an "await" statement.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, yes I try to understand it.
I meant, how could I tell the `send` function to end when the `recieve` function is ended, since those are two different function?
When I try to add a variable `stop` on the `send_recieve` function, changing to 1 when the recieve function is ended, it isn't taken into account in the `send` function, I can't add a condition about this `stop` variable.

Answer (score 0):

> how could I tell the `send` function to end when the `receive` function is ended

`asyncio.gather()` waits for both functions to finish. You can instead wait for either function to finish by replacing:

```
send_result, receive_result = await asyncio.gather(send(), receive())
```

with:

```
await asyncio.wait(
    [asyncio.create_task(send()), asyncio.create_task(receive())],
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
)
```

(Note that "results" of `send` and `receive` you retrieved from `gather()` don't make sense since neither function returns a useful value.)

Comment: You're a genius thank you! I understand I missed digging into this part ! It does work perfectly thanks a lot! 
Yes indeed the two results are useless for now.